# Show that the joint distribution of $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ belongs to a two-parameter exponential family.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, logistic-regression

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ be ind $ \sim\text{Ber}(\theta_i)$ where

\begin{equation}
        \theta_i = P(X_i=1)=\frac{\exp(\alpha+\beta t_i)}{1+\exp(\alpha + \beta t_i)}
\end{equation}

where $t_1, t_2, \dots, t_n$ are known constants.  Show that the joint distribution of $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ belongs to a two-parameter exponential family.

$\bf{My Attempt (WIP) :}$
We can start by finding the joint pmf of $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$

\begin{align*}
        f(\mathbf{X}) &= \prod_{i=1}^n \theta_i^{x_i} (1-\theta_i)^{1-x_i}\\
        &=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{(e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})^{x_i}}{ (1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})^{x_i}} (1-\frac{e^{\alpha+\beta t_i}}{1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i}})^{1-x_i}\\
        &=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{(e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})^{x_i}}{ (1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})^{x_i}} (\frac{1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i}}{1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i}}-\frac{e^{\alpha+\beta t_i}}{1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i}})^{1-x_i}\\
        &=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{(e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})^{x_i}}{ (1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})^{x_i}} (\frac{1}{1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i}})^{1-x_i}\\
        &=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{(e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})^{x_i}}{ (1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})^{x_i + 1 - x_i}}  \\
        &=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{e^{\alpha x_i+\beta t_ix_i}}{1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i}}\\
        &=\frac{e^{\alpha\sum_{i=1}^n x_i+\beta\sum_{i=1}^n t_i x_i} }{\prod_{i=1}^n{(1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})}}
    \end{align*}

This is exponential family with $T(x) = (\sum x_i, \sum t_i x_i)$,  $\eta= (\alpha, \beta)$, and $A(\eta) =A(\eta)=\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n{(1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})}}$

Comment: If each $X_i$ is Bernoulli with a parameter $\theta_i$ that depends on the index $i$, then they cannot be called iid, since they are not identically distributed.

Comment: $\dfrac{\exp(\alpha-\beta t_i)}{1+\exp(\alpha + \beta t_i)}$ looks strange while $\dfrac{\exp(\alpha+\beta t_i)}{1+\exp(\alpha + \beta t_i)}$  or perhaps $\dfrac{\exp(\alpha-\beta t_i)}{1+\exp(\alpha - \beta t_i)}$  would look more natural to investigate as having simple log-odds

Comment: @henry and Heropup You are both correct, i fixed my typos, it should have been independent not iid, and the numerator should be a + not a -, both are fixed in the problem

Comment: Where have you written the joint pmf of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$? It is not the product of the $\theta_i$'s, but a product of the Bernoulli pmfs. Try again.

Comment: @StubbornAtom How do you joint distribution when the distributions are not iid? I am attempting to work through it, but not sure how if I cant turn the product into sums in the exponents

Comment: It's the **independence** of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ that allows you to write $f(\boldsymbol x)=\prod_{i=1}^n \theta_i^{x_i} (1-\theta_i)^{1-x_i}$ where $x_i\in \{0,1\}$ for every $i$. Substitute the expression for $\theta_i$ and focus on the term $\prod_{i=1}^n (e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})^{x_i}=\prod_{i=1}^n e^{\alpha x_i+\beta t_ix_i}$. Why can't you turn this product into sums in the exponents?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I took your advice, and focused on that term and I believe I was able to get to a solution (I updated my post and added that its a WIP for now). I tried to do some algebra to show simply the formula so that I could focus on just $\prod_{i=1}^n e^{\alpha x_i+\beta t_ix_i}$ however i am getting stuck. Is there a specific reason (or am i missing something in my algebra) that I can just focus on that piece?

Comment: @StubbornAtom actually I think I figured out my algebra mistake, does what I have now make sense?

Comment: In the final step the denominator should just be $\prod (1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})$. You can post a detailed answer below.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks for all your help. I have a much clearer understanding of how to do a problem like this now

Answer (score 1):

We can start by finding the joint pmf of $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$

\begin{align*}
        f(\mathbf{X}) &= \prod_{i=1}^n \theta_i^{x_i} (1-\theta_i)^{1-x_i}\\
        &=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{(e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})^{x_i}}{ (1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})^{x_i}} (1-\frac{e^{\alpha+\beta t_i}}{1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i}})^{1-x_i}\\
        &=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{(e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})^{x_i}}{ (1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})^{x_i}} (\frac{1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i}}{1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i}}-\frac{e^{\alpha+\beta t_i}}{1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i}})^{1-x_i}\\
        &=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{(e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})^{x_i}}{ (1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})^{x_i}} (\frac{1}{1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i}})^{1-x_i}\\
        &=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{(e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})^{x_i}}{ (1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})^{x_i + 1 - x_i}}  \\
        &=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{e^{\alpha x_i+\beta t_ix_i}}{1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i}}\\
        &=\frac{e^{\alpha\sum_{i=1}^n x_i+\beta\sum_{i=1}^n t_i x_i} }{\prod_{i=1}^n{(1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})}}
    \end{align*}

This is exponential family with $T(x) = (\sum x_i, \sum t_i x_i)$,  $\eta= (\alpha, \beta)$, and $A(\eta) =A(\eta)=\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n{(1+e^{\alpha+\beta t_i})}}$